# Visualforce: How to render multiple records, 1/page in a single PDF

Tags: visualforce, soql, pdf

I would like to render PDF page base on the amount of record I retrieve using SOQL.

example If I have 10 invoice forms, I should be able to render 10 pages in 1 PDF.

Comment: did you already try something .. it's not clear what you're asking or what your specific issue is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible with having some extra `css`.
Wrap your invoice data with a div and introduce css class as below

```
<style>
.page-break {
        page-break-before:always;
    }
.page-break:first-child {
         page-break-before: avoid;
    }

@page {
        size: A4;
        @bottom-center {
            content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
        }
    }
</style>

<apex:repeat value="{!yourList}" var="item">
  <div class="page-break" >
    <!-- Your content -->
  </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

`page-break` css class help you to start every new child of your list in a new page. And in above `.page-break:first-child` is for avoiding generating empty first page. `@page` is an additional but thought to add it since in this kind of scenario it's valuable. It's giving you in which page are you out of how many pages.

Comment: Neat solution to the blank page at the end if using page-break-after

Comment: Glad to help you @shunjieNeo :)

Comment: HI highfive! But I have a same kind of scenario where I have multiple page block table sections and I need to repeat previous page's column headers if there is a page break needed for last page's last section. Can you suggest me a way out? here:-   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56935/records-truncated-end-of-page-in-pdf