# Records truncated end of page in PDF

Tags: apex, controller, pdf, tabpanel

I have an apex PDF page. There are five different tabpanels to show records. Now when number of records increases the last record of last panel in a page gets segregated to the next page. In such cases I need to repeat the last tab panel of previous page along with it's headers in next one and then show the truncated record in next page. Can someone suggest a way out here?

Apex Page:

Incident Details for DMs/RMs

Page  of

```
        <apex:outputField style="margin-left:-10px;width:200px;" value="{!Incident__c.Name}"/>
        <apex:outputField style="margin-left:-10px;width:200px;" value="{!Incident__c.Rep_Lookup_id__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField style="margin-left:-10px;width:200px;" value="{!Incident__c.Report_Publish_date__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField style="margin-left:-10px;width:200px;" value="{!Incident__c.Status_abv__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField style="margin-left:-10px;width:200px;" value="{!Incident__c.No_Of_Transactions_abv__c}"/>                                                
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>    
<apex:pageBlock title="Incident Transactions">
    <!--<apex:tabPanel switchType="client">-->

        <!--<apex:tab label="HCP Calls">
        <a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_blank">Tutorials Point</a>
        <!--<a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_blank">Tutorials Point</a>
        <a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_self">Tutorials Point</a>--!-->


       <!-- <apex:tab label="Samples">
        <a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_self">Tutorials Point</a>
        </apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="Speaker Program Attendees">

        </apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="Synch Rate">

        </apex:tab>                               
    </apex:tabPanel>-->

   <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListHCPDetail.size>0, true, false)}">
   <apex:tabPanel >
   <apex:tab label="HCP Calls" >

    <apex:pageBlockTable columns="9" value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >

    <div class="page-break" >
<!-- Your content -->
    </div>
    <apex:column headerValue="Professional Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c}" />

     <!-- Need to put Profname string here from the map -->
    <apex:column headerValue=" ABS on Call" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/>
    <apex:column value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/> 
    <apex:column headerValue=" Professional Address" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/>
    <apex:column value="{!itr.Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/> 
    <apex:column headerValue=" Associated Prescriber" value="{!itr.Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/>
    <apex:column headerValue=" Product" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/>
    <apex:column headerValue=" Activity Date" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/> 
    <apex:column headerValue=" Outcome - LOV" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/>



    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>  


    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListHCPSamples.size>0, true, false)}">
    <apex:tabPanel >
    <apex:tab label="Samples" >
    <apex:pageBlockTable columns="10" value="{!oIncTranListHCPSamples }" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
    <apex:column headerValue="Sample Type" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"  value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Professional Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c}  {!itr.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Professional Address" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Product" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Quantity (for hand samples, ESR, and DTP/BRC tied to rep)" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>


    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListHCPSpeaker.size>0, true, false)}">
    <apex:tabPanel >
    <apex:tab label="Speaker Program Attendees" >

     <apex:pageBlockTable columns="9" value="{!oIncTranListHCPSpeaker }" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
    <apex:column headerValue="Professional Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c}  {!itr.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Professional Address" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Product" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Program Name, Date and Location" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListSynch.size>0, true, false)}">
    <apex:tabPanel >
    <apex:tab label="Synch report">

     <apex:pageBlockTable columns="6" value="{!oIncTranListSynch}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
    <apex:column headerValue="Date of Previous Synchronization" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Date of Last Synchronization" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Days between Synchronization" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListHCI.size>0, true, false)}">
    <apex:tabPanel >
    <apex:tab label="HCI/HCO Calls" >

     <apex:pageBlockTable columns="10" value="{!oIncTranListHCI}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
    <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Account Address" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Location_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Role" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Attendee_Role_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Detail" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>


    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListPharmacy.size>0, true, false)}">
    <apex:tabPanel >
    <apex:tab label="Pharmacy Calls" >

     <apex:pageBlockTable columns="10" value="{!oIncTranListPharmacy}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
     <div class="page-break" >
<!-- Your content -->
     </div>
    <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Account Address" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Location_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Role" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Attendee_Role_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Detail" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

    </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 6):

Referencing this CSS from an included stylesheet (or otherwise making sure that the definition stays in the `<head></head>` section of the page):

```
table {
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
}
```

puts a header at the start of each new page where a table crosses a page boundary. You can run this test case to see it working:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="cs" renderAs="PDF" >

<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.PdfCss}"/>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <apex:repeat value="{!cs}" var="c">
        <tr><td>{!c.Name}</td></tr>
        </apex:repeat>
        <!-- Easy way to get more than one page of rows with default controller -->
        <apex:repeat value="{!cs}" var="c">
        <tr><td>{!c.Name}</td></tr>
        </apex:repeat>
        <apex:repeat value="{!cs}" var="c">
        <tr><td>{!c.Name}</td></tr>
        </apex:repeat>
        <apex:repeat value="{!cs}" var="c">
        <tr><td>{!c.Name}</td></tr>
        </apex:repeat>
        <apex:repeat value="{!cs}" var="c">
        </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>

</apex:page>
```

Note that this is a feature of the present implementation - "fs" is presumably short for [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) - and is not AFAIK documented by Salesforce.

**PS** You may get lucky and create working PDF output using apex:pageBlockTable. But Salesforce lists that tag as one of the "Components That Are Unsafe to Use in a PDF" in [Best Practices for Rendering PDFs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm) so a safer approach is to use an apex:repeat tab and HTML markup for the PDF case. (Develop the page using renderAs="HTML" so you can debug the HTML output and then switch to renderAs="PDF" at the end.)

Comment: Keith C -- you need to write the definitive guide on PDF styling of VF pages :-) I find such styling issues to be one of the most frustrating things I've ever had to do with SFDC.

Comment: @crop1645 Yeah it would have been helpful if Salesforce had documented the CSS available in the underlying implementation code...

Comment: Thanks Keith! But I have an apex page with Apex block table approach. Can you please let me know the needful for my page? Please it updated in the question

Comment: @SFDC_GEEK As an apex:pageBlockTable just emits a HTML table the CSS I posted is still appropriate. But see the PS I added to the answer.

Comment: Keith! I am new to salesforce and can't get your words. Can you please do the implementation here for me? where should I put the table section , in CSS file that I have used?

Comment: @SFDC_GEEK You put the HTML tags in the Visualforce page and put the CSS in a separate static resource.